# Disable pasting highlighted text when a right-click action is made in tkinter on OS X

Tags: python, tkinter

It appears that every time all of the text in a widget is highlighted, right clicking on the widget pastes the highlighted text.

To replicate:
- Copy all the text in a text or entry widget
- Right click in the middle of the highlighted text
- Highlighted text is pasted where ever you right-clicked.

Any ideas on how to fix this? It's similar to the behavior of the famous highlight and middle-click to paste highlighted text on any linux box.

It's worth noting that the keysym to the right-click button is `<Button-2>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using the .selection_clear() method inside of the function triggered in a .bind_class() method.

```
frame.bind_class("Text", sequence='<Button-2>', func=self.contextMenuPopup)

def contextMenuPopup:
    # do stuff here ...
    contextOfWidget.selection_clear()
    return
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.