# Tkinter automatically pasting text upon right click when not supposed to

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, listbox, paste

Tkinter is automatically pasting text into an entry box when I right click inside of it.  The strange thing is, it pastes the name from a listbox item that has been selected, or the highlighted text of an entry box.  Here is how to replicate the issue:

**Case I**

After selecting an item from a list box, or generating the event `"<<ListboxSelect>>"`, right clicking in any entry box will paste the name of the most recently selected listbox item.  Problem resolves itself when you highlight some text, then unhighlight it.

**Case II**

If some text is already highlighted from an entry box, it will paste highlighted text when you right click on any other entry box.  Problem is resolved when text is unhighlighted.

After doing some research, I found an issue similar to mine [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470286/disable-pasting-highlighted-text-when-a-right-click-action-is-made-in-tkinter-on).  It appears this is an event that happens on OS X and not other systems (I could be mistaken, I primarily use Macintosh).  Is there a solution to this problem? I'm not too worried about my example in *case II*, but more so in *case I*.

Here is some code I wrote that replicates the problem:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def generate_event(event=None):

    root.event_generate("<<ListboxSelect>>")
    list.select_set("end")
    list.activate("anchor")

root = tk.Tk()

list = tk.Listbox(root)
list.pack()

text_var = tk.StringVar()  # I used a StringVar because that is what is used in my original code.
text_box = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=text_var)
text_box.pack()

button = ttk.Button(text="Press me!", command=generate_event)
button.pack()

list.insert("end", "Test")
list.insert("end", "Hello")

root.mainloop()
```

**How I've Tried to Fix the Problem:**

I have tried clearing the clipboard using `clipboard_clear()`, but it seems the clipboard has nothing to do with the problem.  I have tried disabling `<Button-2>` and `<Button-3>` using `unbind_all()`.  I have even tried using the solution from the link provided above (I might not be implementing it right).

Python version: 3.4

OS: Yosemite

Comment: is this problem happening only on OSX? Is it the native version of tkinter, or one that requires an X11 server? On some (most? all?) linux systems, one of the mouse buttons will immediately paste whatever is selected.

Comment: I believe it is the native version.  It is the tkinter that is included when you download Python [from here](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/ "Python Releases for Mac OS X").  I don't know if only OS X is affected; I don't have a Windows machine to test on.

Comment: I was having the same problem, but I found the fix at this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470286/disable-pasting-highlighted-text-when-a-right-click-action-is-made-in-tkinter-on?lq=1).